# How do I use the '?' operator in mvc?

Tags: asp.net, nullable, optional-parameters

I have an MVC application and I want to use this `?` option.

Please tell me how I can do this. I have written:

```
int? isfeature;
```

but, while inserting the value in database, how do I use it?

It is giving following error:

```
Cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int'.
```

Comment: Try providing a little more detail, including some sample code showing what you're trying to do.

Comment: And the programming language you are working in!

Comment: Cleaned up a bit. Please check that I haven't changed the underlying nature of your question.

Answer (score 4):

int? is a shorthand for Nullable<int>, which means that the value can either be an integer or null. To convert a Nullable<int> to an int, use

```
int? ni = 2;
int i = (int)ni;
```

or

```
int? ni = 2;
int i = ni.Value;
```

This will throw an exception if the value is null, so you can also use

```
int? ni = null;
int i = ni ?? 0;
```

to use 0 as a default value.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

`$foo = $foo == 1 ? $foo : $bar;`

Because I don't understand much of your question...